# How to create a loop in R to calculate a value for each column?

Tags: r, loops, sapply

I wanted to calculate the standard deviation for each column in my data set below:

```
    a b c
[1,] 1 4 7
[2,] 2 5 8
[3,] 3 6 9
```

I tried creating a loop like this:

```
for (x in 1:3){
  sdcol=sd(data[,x])
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in data[, x] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Can you help me with such a loop?

Thanks

Comment: `apply(data, 2, sd)` Or `matrixStats::colSds(data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### EDIT

I suggest you try this command, which is faster than a `for` cycle. Be sure that your variables are all numeric. The `na.rm = TRUE` argument is useful if your columns contain missing values

```
sapply(data, sd, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Example

```
sapply(iris[,1:4], sd, na.rm = TRUE)
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
   0.8280661    0.4358663    1.7652982    0.7622377
```

Comment: hi thank you for the answer, I apply it and get this error: > sapply(x[,1:3], sd)
Error: C stack usage  15923808 is too close to the limit

Comment: How big is your dataset? Is your workspace full of objects, or your RAM full?

Comment: I run the command (> sapply(data[,1:3], sd)) But I get NA values:
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

Comment: It's because you have missing values in your columns. You need to add `na.rm = TRUE` that will be passed to function `sd`. I update my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
     summarise_at(1:4, sd, na.rm = TRUE)
```